# regular expression for valid 2 digit decimal number

Tags: php, regex

I want to have a validation in php for price which can be 100 or 100.45
The 2 decimal places will be optional.

Now the validation should allow only digits.

So far i managed to achieve it

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/', "100"))
{
    echo "Invalid";
}
else
{
    echo "Valid";
}
```

but the issue here is that it is showing valid even if i enter 100a.00 or 100a or 100.a00

Please help me in fixing it so that only digits are allowed i.e 100 or 100.00 format

Comment: Have you tried adding a `$` at the end, to match the end of the string? At the moment, it's matching a valid sequence of characters at the start with `^`, so `100a` is valid - the a is ignored, because the 100 is valid.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/', "100"))
```

The `$` denotes the "end of a string": http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php

Comment: what if the number length is more than 2.

Answer (score 7):

Lacks a $ in your regex.
Presently, the first 3 characters in '100a...' match your regex.

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/', "100")
```

should do the trick.